# Where can I find statistics for numbers of 16-20 year olds in the world?

Tags: data-request, markets

Where can I find statistics about how many 16-20 years old people do live in the world?

If there is no such statistics, how about people in this age-range in europe+amerika?

Comment: For the EU http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/data/database

Answer (score 2):

That's not really an economics question, so it's probably off-topic. However, the US Census Bureau seems to track this [here](https://www.census.gov/population/international/data/idb/worldpop.php) over time by sex.